# Why can't I add items to the list in Python correctly?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm just trying to add items to the list and I can't! My code:

```
    import numpy as np
    data = [[]] * 10
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        slice = np.random.randn(100, 100, 3)
        print('before: ', np.shape(data))
        print('slice: ', np.shape(slice))
        data[i].append(slice)
        print('after: ', np.shape(data))
```

Result is the following:

```
before:  (10, 0)
slice:  (100, 100, 3)
after:  (10, 1, 100, 100, 3)

...

before:  (10, 0)
slice:  (100, 100, 3)
after:  (10, 10, 100, 100, 3)
```

So, (100, 100, 3) wasn't inserted to the correct position in `data[0]`, but additional dimension was created! Why? And how can I avoid it?

The correct dimension of the result list should be (10, **1**, 100, 100, 3) - not (10, **10**, 100, 100, 3).

Comment: `data = list()` and then `data.append(slice)`

Comment: Or `data[i] = slice`

Comment: you just need to make sure that data only contains 10 when it is initialized. and then you can append.

Comment: I've just fixed serious error in my question.

Comment: Sorry, there were mistype again. Finally, it's correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main culprit is

```
data = [[]] * 10
```

Which creates a single empty list and replicates it 9 times more, so in effect you are inserting to the same list 10 times. For example:

```
In [113]: data = [[]] * 10

In [114]: data[0].append(1)

In [115]: data
Out[115]: [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

---

You should either

1. create a place-holder list and then insert at the ith element, or
2. create an empty list `[]` and call `.append`

But not both.

I would recommend declaring an empty `list`:

```
data = [[] for _ in range(10)]
```

Now, call `.append` in the loop:

```
data.append(slice)
```

You can convert the resultant to an array using `data = np.array(data)`. Here's a sample:

```
data = [[] for _ in range(10)]

 for i in range(0, len(data)):
     slice = np.random.randn(100, 100, 3)
     data[i].append(slice)


print(np.array(data).shape)
(10, 1, 100, 100, 3)
```

Comment: data[i] = slice won't work, because I want to add many 'slices' to each data[i]! With my code when I'm trying to add 10 slices it adds me 10*10 slices.

Comment: @Dmitry That's because you're using `data = [[]] * 10` which creates one list and replicates it 9 times, so you're accessing the same list 10 times. In my answer, I spell out some alternatives.

Comment: I've just fixed serious error in my question. Do you see my problem now?

Comment: I want to add 10 'slices' as items of corresponding 10 lists `data[i]`. The correct dimension of the result list should be (10, **1**, 100, 100, 3). But I actually get with my code (10, **10**, 100, 100, 3). So, how can I achieve (10, **1**, 100, 100, 3)?

Comment: @Dmitry I told you everything you need to do. But it appears you still didn't follow. No problem, I've added a new example at the bottom of my answer.